# Django - Custom Template Tag passing keyword args

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

How can I create a custom template tag to use keyword args in my template?

custom_templates.py

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag

def custom_tag_field(value, kwarg1=False, kwarg2=False):
    t = template.loader.get_template('some_template.html')
    return t.render(template.Context({'value': value, 'kwarg1':kwarg1, 'kwarg2': kwarg2}))
```

template.py

```
{% load custom_templates  %}
```

....

I would like to use the custom template tag with keywords args like this:

```
{% custom_tag_field form.somefield "value" kwarg1="somearg1" kwarg2="somearg2" %)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you are :

A tag that parses args ang kwargs like the url tag:

```
{% get_with_args_and_kwargs somevar,"sometext",kwarg1=someothervar %}
```

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1113/

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays this work as you'd expect, see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags).